# How to cross-reference the second equation in a two-row 'eqnarray' environment with a single \label instruction?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, eqnarray

I have written a two-row equation in this way:

```
\begin{eqnarray}\label{cov}
a \\ & =& b.
\end{eqnarray}
```

with as a result

[image]

If I write `(\ref{cov})` I get "(10)". Do you know how to create a cross-reference to equation (11) instead? Thanks.

Comment: put the `\label` on the 2nd row. it is a bit weird to number half an equation, consider adding `\nonumber` to the first row, so you only get (10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the `\label` instruction *after* rather than before `\\` if you want to be able to cross-reference the second equation.

[image]

On a different topic: [Don't use the `eqnarray` environment.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) [No ifs, ands, or buts.](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) [No way, no how.](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/) Do please load the `amsmath` package and employ that package's `align` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\setcounter{equation}{9} % just for this example
\begin{eqnarray}
a \\ &=& b. \label{cov}
\end{eqnarray}
A cross-reference to equation (\ref{cov}).
\end{document}
```